# legacy-install-failure error for sentence piece in jac

Tags: jaseci

We recently had to reset our virtual environment, and thus had to reinstall jaseci_ai_kit via pip install jaseci_ai_kit. This commands runs fine for everyone in our group with a windows computer, but those of us with a mac receive a "legacy-install-failure" error for a package called sentencepiece. We were having trouble debugging this error ourselves (and sadly can't use any intent transitions until we do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux you solve it by using this command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y install --no-install-recommends git g++ build-essential pkg-config cmake
```